# reversing hash.sort_by in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

Simple enough but Im drawing a blank on it.

```
 @sortedHash = @otherHash.sort_by { |k,v| v }
```

This stores the has based on key value in ascending order. in other words first value in hash is lowest. How do i reverse (descending order) it so that the highest value is at the top?

```
 @sortedInternalLinksHash = @countHash.sort_by { |k,v| -v }
 @sortedInternalLinksHash = @countHash.sort_by { |k,v| !v }
```

Comment: Hashes are unsorted, do you mean an array of hashes?

Comment: @Gazler: hashes are unsorted in ruby 1.8.7 not in 1.9.2

Comment: @Gazler. This is why I'm sorting the has by its value. I am actually using 1.8.7.

Comment: Sorting by `-v` should work and saves you from sorting and then reversing afterwards.

Comment: Sorting by `-v` only works if your values can be negated. No good if they're strings, for example. So the `.reverse` method has the advantage of working regardless of value type...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@sortedInternalLinksHash = @countHash.sort_by { |k,v| v }.reverse
```

Comment: Does exactly what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:

`@sortedInternalLinksHash = @countHash.sort_by { |_,v| - v }`